# Why need load_ptr_acquire?

Tags: java, c++, jvm

See the following code:

```
intptr_t load_ptr_acquire(volatile intptr_t*   p) { return *p; }
```

Is it useless?
If use the function as this:

```
intptr_t p = some value;
int value = (int)load_ptr_acquire(&p);
```

Why need that function instead of writing directly:

```
int value = (int)p;
```

I want to know this trick.

The code above is from jdk8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/memory/metaspace.cpp line 86.

Comment: What do you understand by `volatile`?

Comment: I'm not sure that Hotspot should be considered a masterpiece of C++ coding. Read with care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here,I know why need that function.

That is just because of 'volatile' reserved keyword，which offer the memory ordering,as p may be accessed by mutiple threads or CPUs.